# C# DATE TIME CONVERSIONS WITH TIME ZONES

Tags: c#, rest, time

Im consuming a REST api that returns a datetime in the format **2022-09-08T00:21:32.712+03:00** this translates to 08/09/2022 00:21. How do I convert a date value say **08/09/2022 00:21** to the format **2022-09-08T00:21:32.712+03:00** in C#? I have tried below cord without success

```
    string NIRA_CREATEDDATE_FORMATED = NIRA_CREATEDDATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an ISO 8601 format. C# will output it if you use the "o" format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
```

Note that you'll likely see a higher level of precision than the one you've provided, but that won't typically matter.